# Passenger repository certificate verification failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, debian, passenger

I want to install Passenger server on my virtual machine, so I do the following:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list"
sudo chown root: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

But after I update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this errors:

```
Err https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com trusty/main amd64 Packages       
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Err https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com trusty/main i386 Packages        
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Ign https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com trusty/main Translation-en_US    
Ign https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com trusty/main Translation-en       
Fetched 2,573 kB in 11s (220 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

W: Failed to fetch https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I already installed it previously many times and had no problems. I have no idea what might go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed that by reinstalling Ubuntu on clean VM. 
This issue might appeared because I copied my VM's without turning it off.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to re-install certificates as described [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu). Maybe they has been changed.

2) Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c) post. It describe similar problem and possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to disable peer-verification

Possible Docker Command could be:

```
RUN echo 'Acquire::https::oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com::Verify-Peer "false";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99phusionpassenger-cert
```

You may also like to read the solution posted on another thread: [server certificate verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21181447/144408)