# curl server certificate verification failure while deploying Shiny app on RStudio Connect

Tags: r, ssl, curl, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to deploy a Shiny application on a local server using RStudio Connect. One of the packages that I am using in the app has been installed from GitHub (https://github.com/rasmusab/fullcalendar). The deployment of the app fails when it is trying to install this package with a `curl: (60) server certificate verification failed` error.

I have tried `export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1` as well as `git config --global http.sslverify false` as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c). But the error persists during deployment. What else can I try here?

Comment: I assume the usual ``options(RCurlOptions = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))`` didn't  work too?

Comment: Or ``set_config( config( ssl.verifypeer = 0L ) ) ``

Comment: @Nutle no, these didn't work either.