# Jenkins failed to connect to gitea repository

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins, certificate, gitea

I am currently facing an issue where I try to connect Jenkins with my Gitea repository. When I do so, and want to enter my Gitea Repository, i recieve an error message telling me the following:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://git.********/repo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: fatal: unable to access https://git.********/repo.git: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

So far I´ve tried to manually add an update my certificates on the server Jenkins is running on, but this didnt work out.
One thing I´d like to mention is, that I have apparantly no crlfile as the error says. I trie to manually add it, but since my Server doesnt have a ca.key file, i am not able to manually configure one by myself (unless I just missed out something).
But is this file realy neccesary? Because all it does is telling which Certificates are forbidden so to say, right?

Would be delighted about every solution suggested.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c Seems similar to me

Answer (score 1):

> This is because of ssh-key expired or changed in the machine..
>   Try cloning he code once locally if it doesnt works create new ssh-key using (ssh-keygen) and copy it into codeclub

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
i tried it with ssh-keygen but sadly it didnt worked out for me