# Fetching gitlab repo gives server certificate verification failed and using with https( personal access token) instead of ssh

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

Facing an error while fetching Git repo using jenkins with HTTPS. I used personal access token for https to clone the repo instead of ssh

The Error is stderr: fatal: unable to access git and my repo..server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Image attached below with error

[image]

Comment: Looks like the server is not using an official ssl certificate.

Comment: this issue is with only while I am using https but not with shh..How to solve this??

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c)