# I am facing a problem in initializing a repo, which throws the following errors

Tags: repo

Whenever I do a repo init, I am getting the following errors and not able to get the repo. Here I am doing repo init based on the latest tag.

repo command :

```
repo init -u ssh://10.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx/test-manifest -b ref/tags/development -m lat_dev.xml
```

> fatal: Cannot get
>   https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
>
> fatal: error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed (_ssl.c:590)
>
> fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove
>   '.repo/repo'

Could anyone help me out in this problem?

Comment: Looks like a certificate problem. You on Windows or Linux? Or something else?

Comment: I am trying to perform this in Linux platform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c)