# pkgdown::deploy_to_branch() SSL cert error

Tags: r, github-pages, pkgdown

I've been using `pkgdown::deploy_to_branch()` for awhile now to publish my docs on the `gh-pages` branch of my repo, but as of this week it stopped working and has started giving me the following error:

```
Error: callr subprocess failed: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Type .Last.error.trace to see where the error occurred 
7.
stop(cond) at errors.R#275
6.
throw(newerr, parent = remerr[[2]]) at result.R#70
5.
get_result(output = out, options) at eval.R#176
4.
callr::r(function(..., crayon_enabled, crayon_colors, pkgdown_internet) {
    options(crayon.enabled = crayon_enabled, crayon.colors = crayon_colors, 
        pkgdown.internet = pkgdown_internet)
    pkgdown::build_site(...) ... at build.r#432
3.
build_site_external(pkg = pkg, examples = examples, run_dont_run = run_dont_run, 
    seed = seed, lazy = lazy, override = override, preview = preview, 
    devel = devel) at build.r#385
2.
build_site(pkg, devel = FALSE, preview = FALSE, install = FALSE, 
    ...) at deploy-site.R#172
1.
pkgdown::deploy_to_branch()
```

When I tried to debug and got deeper into the function, this is the error I got trying to call `build_site()` directly:

[image: build_site() stack trace]

Admittedly, authentication of all sorts is consistently baffling to me, but what has me really baffled is that my auth with github seems to be working in all other ways. I have it cloned with SSH. I can push and pull to my heart's content when I do it manually or through the RStudio GUI. Also, I can't figure out anything that has changed since the time when this *was* working.

Anyway, any help is much appreciated. I've also looked at a few other issues that came up when I googled the error ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c), for example) but none of them seem to be relevant to my situation where git is working fine *except* in this call.

Some details:

- I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1054-aws x86_64)
- R 4.0.3
- pkgdown 1.6.1
- I tried this with two different repos ([1](https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/bbr) and [2](https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/mrgvalidate), both of which were previously working with this same command and the same OS/versions/etc ^

Let me know if there are any more details that would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out this had nothing to do with `pkgdown`. Sorry for blaming you `pkgdown`!

The issue had something to do with [this](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/) which I was lucky enough to stumble onto *the exact day* that it happened. A coworker told me to run the following snippet and it fixed everything.

`sudo apt-get update ;  sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates`