# Cannot pull from gitlab server anymore. CAfile: None CRLfile: None

Tags: git, gitlab, certificate

I have this repository hosted on gitlab that I have always been able to sync to on my machine.
But for the past few days, I cannot push nor pull anymore. This is happening with every repository.
I get the following error:

`fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.(company).ch/(user)/(repo).git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none`

I have read other similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21181231/6133698), but they always have a certificate which is not trusted and the solution is to trust that certificate. But in my case, there doesn't seem to be a certificate I can trust. Also I do not understand why it just suddenly stopped working.

Note:

This is happening on every instance of my remote machines in a server, but not on my local machine. My colleagues have not encountered this problem in either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=expired%20certificate