# understanding syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c/21181447#21181447), which suggesting running this command:

```
sudo bash -c "echo -n | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $hostname:$port -servername $hostname \
    2>/dev/null  | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'  \
    >> $trust_cert_file_location"
```

But I'm getting:

> syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Now, I've figured out that it's probably because of either the > or >> operators in the command. I've found answers saying to escape such characters with quotes, but they all talk about cases when the '>' characters are a part of a simple text. What to do when it's an actual operator like in my case?

Comment: I suggest to remove within `"` and `"` both backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are coping some white spaces after the `\`.

Suggesting to remove the new line separator:

```
 sudo bash -c "echo -n | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $hostname:$port -servername $hostname 2>/dev/null  | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'  >> $trust_cert_file_location"
```

Suggesting to test if you get all certificates or just the first one.